# How to convert timezone using pymysql python

Tags: python

```
scheduled_start_time = "12:00:00"
timezone_name = "America/New_York"
cursor.execute('SELECT CONVERT_TZ("+str(scheduled_start_time)+","UTC","+str(timezone_name)+")')
convert_scheduled_start_time = cursor.fetchone()
print(convert_scheduled_start_time)
```

Now my output is

```
{'CONVERT_TZ("+str(scheduled_start_time)+","UTC","+str(timezone_name)+")': None}
```

my required output is `16:00:00`. Is there any solution convert timezone using sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's no point to cast string into a string (i.e. `str(scheduled_start_time)`) but besides that, you are using single quotes and double quotes in the wrong places (even SO's syntax highlighting marks the whole argument to `execute()` as one big string and not concatenated strings). Fixed concatenation should look like

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT CONVERT_TZ('" + scheduled_start_time + "', 'UTC', '" + timezone_name + "')")
```

that would produce expected final string to be

```sql
{'CONVERT_TZ(\'12:00:00\', \'UTC\', \'America/New_York\')': datetime.time(8, 0)}
```

BTW: I'd recommend dropping string concatenation and use placeholders instead:

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT CONVERT_TZ(%s, 'UTC', %s)", (scheduled_start_time, timezone_name))
```